# Удалённая отладка shared lib в Netbeans 8.1

Tags: c++, netbeans

Добрый день!

Имеется уже скомпилированное С++ приложение на mipsel плате с возможностью подключения сторонних .so библиотек (в качестве API) и хост машина amd64 с установленными Ubuntu 16.04/Netbeans. Каким образом можно отладить свою библиотеку для этого приложения на хост машине в Netbeans? Я добавил Build host mipsel устройства и создал проект С/C++ Dynamic Library. Что дальше?